# Filter by merged cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to filter a data table by date values. Unfortunately the date cells are merged like so:

[image]

So if I would write

```
=FILTER(B1:B; A1 >= DATE(2020, 4, 1))
```

I only get every other value in Column B. I guess I should combine two filters, one of which has the source offset by one, but then I'd get a range mismatch error, because the source range would be one row shorter than the one in the condition statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
=FILTER(A1:B21, 
            ArrayFormula(vlookup(ROW(1:21),{IF(LEN(A1:A21)>0,ROW(1:21),""),A1:A21},2)) >= DATE(2020, 10, 30))
```

[image]

What we do is create a virtual column for column `A`.

*(Try the partial formula by itself and see how it behaves.)*

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If not we could try finding out why. If yes, please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score -1):

As I do not have enough reputation to comment the other answer I'm adding a new one.
The formula from the previous answer from @marikamitsos works but for a different locale you need to use:

```
=FILTER(A1:B21; 
            ArrayFormula(vlookup(ROW(1:21);{IF(LEN(A1:A21)>0;ROW(1:21);"")\A1:A21};2)) >= DATE(2021; 10; 30))
```